# Why code shows "Error 354 (net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH): The server unexpectedly closed the connection."

Tags: sockets, http, tcp, webserver

I am building my *HTTP WEB SERVER* in *JAVA*.

If client request any file and that file is on that place in server, then server gives that file to client. I also made this code, and it works fine.

**The part of  code, that shows above functionality**,

```
File targ = [CONTAINS ONE FILE]
PrintStream ps;
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(targ.getAbsolutePath());
            while ((n = is.read(buf)) > 0) {
                System.out.println(n);
                ps.write(buf, 0, n);
            }
```

**But now to make my code optimized, I replace this code with below code,**

```
   InputStream is = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    String output = null;

    is = new FileInputStream(targ.getAbsolutePath());
    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        while( (output = reader.readLine()) != null) {
           System.out.println("new line");
           //System.out.println(output);
           ps.print(output);
        }
```

But it sometimes shows one error `Why code shows "Error 354 (net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH): The server unexpectedly closed the connection."`. I didn't understand, why it shows this error. This error is very weird, because server shows `200` code, that means, that file is there.

Help me please.

**Edit no. 1**

```
    char[] buffer = new char[1024*16];
    int k = reader.read(buffer);
    System.out.println("size : " + k);
    do { 
       System.out.println("\tsize is : " + k);
       //System.out.println(output);
       ps.println(buffer);
    }while(  (k = reader.read(buffer)) != -1 );
```

This prints all the file, but for bigger files, it shows unreadable characters.

**It shows below output** *(Snapshot of client browser)*

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You do `output = reader.readLine()` to get the data, which omits the newline characters. Then you `ps.print(output)`, so the newline characters are not sent to the client.

Say you read this

```
Hello\r\n
World\r\n
```

Then you send this:

```
Content-length: 14

HelloWorld
```

And then close the connection, confusing the browser as it still was waiting for the other 4 bytes.

I guess you'll have to use `ps.println(output)`.

You would have seen this if you were monitoring the network traffic, which can prove quite useful when writing or debugging a server that is supposed to communicate using the network.

Anyway this will cause trouble if the newlines of the file and the system have a mismatch (`\n` vs `\r\n`). Say you have this file:

```
Hello\r\n
World\r\n
```

Its length is 14 bytes. However when your system treats a newline when printing as `\n`, your code with `println()` will print this:

```
Hello\n
World\n
```

Which is 12 bytes, not 14. You better just print what you read.

Comment: It works for me. I have two questions from you, 1) Please explain last line of your answer. 2) Is second approach is better/efficient than first one or not ?

Comment: @devsda see edit. And no, it is not better or more efficient, you better just print what you read.

Comment: Thanks for edit. And, I read somewhere that `BufferedReader` is better , that's why I used it. I think buffering is always better than any other method. Is it ?

Comment: That might be true, I don't know, but `BufferedReader` also has a `read()` method. No need to call `readln()`.

Comment: Can you make second method correct, please. So that it follows your words, `You better just print what you read.`.

Comment: I used `readLine()` because it is easy to print. `read()` requires character array, but PrintStream supports byte array. That's why I used `readLine` rather than `read`

Comment: But you should not use `readLine()` because of the potential problems that will cause in this context. Just use `read()` and `write()` as you're working with bytes, not text. Edit: I'm not that familiar with the Java library, but `BufferedReader` seems to be for textual data. That is not suited for this. Use a binary buffered reader.

Comment: Please edit no, 1, as your method works for small files. But shows wrong output for bigger files.

Comment: @devsda now you're mixing `read()` and `println()`. **You** are the one who has to figure out what is going wrong. I cannot see your code run and am not fit for psychic debugging.