# Rails image disappears with error: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

Essentially my problem is that a page loads fine and looks normal. After about 30 seconds it suddenly disappears.

Here's the server log before the error (as loading the page):

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-11 23:53:30 -0400
Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
  Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (0.7ms)
  Rendered layouts/_head.erb (3.3ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.erb (0.9ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.erb (0.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 11ms (Views: 10.5ms)

Started GET "/assets/favicon.ico" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-11 23:53:30 -0400

Started GET "/assets/application.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-11 23:53:30 -0400

Started GET "/assets/home.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-11 23:53:30 -0400

Started GET "/assets/taylor.jpg" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-11 23:53:30 -0400

Started GET "/assets/wide.jpg" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-11 23:53:30 -0400

Started GET "/assets/enchanted_large.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-11 23:53:30 -0400

Started GET "/assets/sad.jpg" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-11 23:53:30 -0400
```

And then suddenly the image dissappears with the client side error (seen in Chrome's dev console):

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH
  http://localhost:3000/assets/taylor.jpg
```

And the only addition to the log is:

```
Started GET "/assets/favicon.ico" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-11 23:54:00 -0400
```

During the 30 seconds of it looking good, chrome has a loading symbol where the favicon goes

My html is rather simple at this point:

```
<div class="home-images">
  <%= image_tag "taylor.jpg", class: "home-image" %>
  <%= image_tag "wide.jpg", class: "home-image hide" %>
  <%= image_tag "sad.jpg", class: "home-image hide" %>
</div>
```

I even took out my javascript completely. I tried removing turbolinks by itself too. It only happens to one image. And I have no idea why...

When I switched the html, it was the same image (taylor) that gave the error:

```
<div class="home-images">
  <%= image_tag "wide.jpg", class: "home-image" %>
  <%= image_tag "taylor.jpg", class: "home-image hide" %>
  <%= image_tag "sad.jpg", class: "home-image hide" %>
</div>
```

All my images are located in my app/assets/images folder

My header looks like this:

```
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Enchanting Events and Design</title>
  <%= favicon_link_tag       "favicon.ico" %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag  "application" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag  "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
```

Comment: what is the size of this http://localhost:3000/assets/taylor.jpg ?

Comment: In a possibly, but maybe not unrelated note: finder is not responding currently (breaks when i enter the folder with the files). I'll get back to you ASAP

Comment: @Raghu it's 350 by 290. Finder works again after restarting my computer, still get same error though

Comment: which server are you running on local? webbrick? if yes then try using thin or mongrel and see if you are getting a different result

Comment: I'm actually using thin

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why code shows "Error 354 (net::ERR\_CONTENT\_LENGTH\_MISMATCH): The server unexpectedly closed the connection."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16357848/why-code-shows-error-354-neterr-content-length-mismatch-the-server-unexpec)

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?

Comment: @chopper No, but it might've only happened locally. Are you having the problem too? I can look back into it

Comment: Yes, Im having the same issue. It's only certain images andIn also only have this issue locally. Unfortunately running rake assets:clean as suggested below did not help. If you have any ideas what may be going on, that would be great.

Comment: Same issue here, really weird. I **solved** it partially by re-saving the image with GIMP. Are there any chance your image was saved with Illustrator or KolourPaint?

Comment: Mine came from the internet, but are you thinking a slightly corrupted file?

Comment: @TMP: Yes, that's the only reason considering I didn't change code to actually "fix" it...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had this issue when I replaced an image using the `mv` command.  This left the timestamp untouched, so it broke the asset caching.  A simple `touch` of the affected file fixed it.

Comment: This may be what happened. It recently happened again for me and re-downloading the image from the src fixed it.

Comment: OH MY LAWD I searched so hard for this very simple answer thank you so much

Answer (score 27):

Ran into the same issue when I edited my image size.

None of the above solutions worked for me, but `rake tmp:clear` did!

Comment: Can confirm this... I resized the image and ran into this issue ;)

Comment: Just to add to it, this might happen at times when you try to use different images with the same name. `rake tmp:clear` did work for me, thanks!

Comment: This is perfect (especially given the OP's handle)

Answer (score 2):

Try "rake assets:clean" and rebuild your asset(if you need). I got working by this magic.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a symptom of another problem with nginx. Please see this article:

[Rails image disappears with error: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22341884/rails-image-disappears-with-error-failed-to-load-resource-neterr-content-len)

I saw the same issue as you, and it turned out to be an nginx permission issue with the underlying cache directory which also caused the problem to be somewhat intermittent.