# Javascript not loading due to net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've got an app that runs fine locally, but barfs in production.  (Classic problem, right?)

In production, the JS isn't firing correctly.  When I open up the browser console, I see this error:

`net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH`

When I look in the network tab of Developer Tools, is shows that it failed on a GET request for text/html.

It's a cryptic error.  I've only found two other SO posts that even mention is and they're unsolved. (For the interested:  [first post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22341884/rails-image-disappears-with-error-failed-to-load-resource-neterr-content-len) and [second post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22183859/javascript-err-content-length-mismatch))

Any idea (1) what it means or (2) how to resolve it?

Answer (score 35):

> I am getting Error: net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH

**Have a look at your server logs to determine what the real issue is.**

For me the problem lay somewhere between nginx and file permissions:

- `tail -f /usr/local/var/log/nginx/error.log` or run `nginx -t` to determine your conf location, where you could specify a custom log path.
- refresh the asset in your browser, eg `http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery/jquery.js`

You may see something like this in the logs:

> "/usr/local/var/run/nginx/proxy_temp/9/04/0000000049" failed (13:
>   Permission denied) while reading upstream for file xyz

Heres how I fixed:

```
sudo nginx -s stop
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/var/run/nginx/*
sudo nginx
```

Comment: In my case Nginx was running as a reverse proxy and I simply runned out of disk space. One look at Nginx logs was enough. Thanks.

Comment: This also solved my issue for getting "net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING" wherein my node server was cutting the file stream short.

Comment: Solved for me too. I was getting ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH when i trying to directly access an image like: http://url.to/assets/image.png. Went through the same steps and after deleting cache folder, the error was gone. Thanks!

Comment: Removing `proxy_temp` then reloading `ngix` fixed it for me.

Answer (score 6):

According to [this bug report](https://codereview.chromium.org/8496016), that error occurs when an external resource length does not match the Content-Length header given in the response.

This might occur because of a misconfigured server, or (as a stretch) maybe some BOM characters got put into the file, or maybe even different lines endings (are you writing on a DOS machine and deploying to a UNIX machine?) may cause issues.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Older response, but I write in node.js (using express.js) on Windows, and since moving the code to an Ubuntu server, I experienced this issue with several content files (not sure which caused the issue). Using dos2unix solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue when trying to interpret JSON results.  It turned out that somewhere along the line an odd character landed in the database - in this instance the culprit was "â??".  It is not clear how this value arrived in the database, but it is likely related to [HTML encoding issues - "Â" character showing up instead of "&nbsp;"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461907/html-encoding-issues-%C3%82-character-showing-up-instead-of-nbsp) Either way, after removing the odd characters, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue
[crit] 6889#0: *14817 open() "/var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp/3/02/0000000023" failed (13: Permission denied) while reading upstream

it was because Nginx worker process were not able to access folder /var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp/  - I just changed the folder permissions and everything started working

Comment: I do `sudo chmod -R 777 /var/lib/nginx/proxy/ ` and everything works fine. There maybe some security issue about that. Can someone else explain it to me?

Comment: dont setup 777...just give read permission to user running Nginx ( may be by adding it to owner group of that folder )

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue developing locally on MAMP and using Chrome as browser. Same problematic websites on the live servers had no such issues. First I thought it was MAMP that was playing around and I checked settings like PHP versions mismatch, apache version etc., reinstalled, but the issue remained. At the end I just switched to using Brave browser (was delaying the shift to Brave for a while anyway) and that fixed it for me.

Hope this helps.